# How do I tell bundle install to use the version of Ruby on my PATH?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler

I'm trying to install my Rails 5 project on Debian. Either running `bundle install` with or without `sudo` results in an error complaining about not having the appropriate version of Ruby, even though when I run `ruby -v` after, you can see the version is 2.4. How do I point `bundle install` to the right version?

```
$ sudo bundle install
[sudo] password for myuser:
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Your Gemfile lists the gem jquery-rails (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake 12.0.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 0.8.6
Using minitest 5.10.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.3

Gem::InstallError: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
An error occurred while installing activesupport (5.0.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install activesupport -v '5.0.4'` succeeds before bundling.

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [armv6l-linux-eabihf]
```

Running without `sudo`:

```
$ bundle install
Your Gemfile lists the gem jquery-rails (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake 12.0.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 0.8.6
Using minitest 5.10.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.3

Gem::InstallError: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
An error occurred while installing activesupport (5.0.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install activesupport -v '5.0.4'` succeeds before bundling.

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [armv6l-linux-eabihf]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke bundle, first of all `bundle` itself gets resolved in `$PATH`. You can check, where the executable of it is located by typing `whereis bundle` or `which bundle`. In my case (Ubuntu 16.04) it's located in `/usr/local/bin/bundle`.

If we execute `cat /usr/local/bin/bundle`, we will get a content of this executable:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/bundle
#!/usr/bin/ruby2.4
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'bundler' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0.a"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/ and Gem::Version.correct?($1) then
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

load Gem.activate_bin_path('bundler', 'bundle', version)
```

As you can see, it's a plain Ruby script, and the top most line (`#!/usr/bin/ruby2.4`) sets the interpreter to execute it.

I suppose, that in your case there is an old Ruby version used, because if you had a Ruby in your system before installing 2.4.0, executable for `gem`  didn't get updated for 2.4 and also uses old Ruby version. You can check this by doing `which gem` (for me `/usr/bin/gem`) and checking file contents with `cat`.

After that you can check available executables of `gem` by typing `whereis gem`:

```
$ whereis gem
gem: /usr/bin/gem /usr/bin/gem2.2 /usr/bin/gem2.4
```

Then you can just remove bundler by typing `gem uninstall bundler` (this should also remove it's executables) and install it again using correct gem, executing:

```
/usr/bin/gem2.4 install bundle
```

That should do the trick, because in executable for bundler you will get Ruby 2.4 as interpreter.

[update-alternatives](https://askubuntu.com/a/532005/730382) command can also be useful for such cases.

As you can see, it's such a headache, so my recommendation is either to use Ruby version manager ([rvm](https://rvm.io/), [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv), etc.), or have only one Ruby version per machine.

Comment: K, so I ran "whereis gem" and got "gem: /usr/bin/gem /usr/bin/gem2.1 /usr/local/bin/gem /usr/share/man/man1/gem.1.gz".  Doesn't look like the most curent version of gem. How do I get that?

Comment: @Dave How have you installed ruby2.4 to your system? Was it compiled from source?

Comment: For Ubuntu I use [this repository](https://launchpad.net/~brightbox/+archive/ubuntu/ruby-ng), and `rubygems-integration` (v 1.10) package also gets installed and setted up to provide /usr/lib/gemX.X when installing Ruby.

Comment: To answer your first question, yes I instaled it from source.

Comment: @Dave Ok, I tried to install Ruby from sources right now, and as I see it generated gem executable in /usr/local/bin/gem. `cat` it and check interpreter. In my case it is `#!/usr/local/bin/ruby`. Then execute /your/path/ruby -v, and if it is the required Ruby, use this gem executable.

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install rails --version 5.0.0
```